# Print Drupal system forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to output "Site information" form in another place. I tried to use drupal_get_form and it does not work as expected

the code in menu callback

```
drupal_get_form('system_site_information_settings');
```

Error message

> Notice: Undefined index: system_site_information_settings in
>   drupal_retrieve_form()

My guess the form ID is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form ID you're using is definitely the right one...[`system_site_information_settings()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_site_information_settings/7) lives in the system.admin.inc file in the core system module. By default it's not included in the page process, you need to include it manually:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'system', 'system.admin');
$form = drupal_get_form('system_site_information_settings');
```